# Is it possible to one method into another file in nodejs and express?

Tags: node.js, express, angular7

how can I use one method into entire project is it possible?
If it's possible please help me with detail.

Thanks Advance

Comment: create a module export it ,then import it and use wherever you want

Comment: thank you for response, can you please give me an exmple.

Comment: Yeah cool ,see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an example its your `log.js` file.You can use module.exports to export a function like this

```
module.exports.log = function (msg) { 
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Now if you want to import it in ,suppose `app.js` file.Just do something like this.

```
var msg = require('./Log.js');// the path is important here 

msg.log('Hello World');
```

In above example you are exporting `log function` ,import it with the way I told and you can use it anywhere you want (after requiring).

Better have a look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) too.

You can also use `ES6` `export` and `import`,something like below

```
export function log(){ } // exports named function log
import { log } from '..filepath/filename'
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) ,describe it elaborately.