# console.log show empty module

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm new with Node.js and begin my training but stuck with the console behavior. 
i try to attach tutorial.js module with app.js so it will display all functions in tutorial.js module.

tutorial.js

```
const sum = (num1,num2) => num1 + num2;
const div = (num1,num2) => num1 / num2;
module.expose=sum;
module.expose=div;
```

app.js

```
const tutorial = require('./tutorial');
console.log(tutorial);
```

console.log(tutorial) display empty module -

```
node app.js
{}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to assign properties to the `exports` object, not the `module`.

Comment: module.expose? or module.exports?

Comment: Yes, either assign to module.exports or exports object.

Comment: tutorial.js

    const sum = (num1,num2) => num1 + num2;
    const div = (num1,num2) => num1 / num2;
    module.exports = {sum, div};  // just make this change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `module.exports` not `module.expose`

```
const sum = (num1,num2) => num1 + num2;
    const div = (num1,num2) => num1 / num2;
    module.exports=sum;
    module.exports=div;
```

For more details look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57105895/7849549)